# i need to get individual words from title and then insert into rankmath as individual keywords

Tags: php

Looking at getting keywords from a post title individually and inserting into rankmath using PHP or a script automatically.

EG title reads

How to make a website earn money with .....

and the code would split it down into
How,to,make,etc and then remove the stopwords and add the remaining into rankmath keywords

I found the below scripts to break up title into single words and then they should be inserted into rankmath is it possible to combine the 2 without affecting site performance. As no idea about coding.

thanks in advance for any help.

```
// Get the global post variable (inside or outside the loop)
 global $post;

 // Seperate title slug by dashes into array
 $the_slug_into_array = explode('-', $post->post_name);

 // Convert array back into a string with comma separation
 $the_keywords = implode(',', $the_slug_into_array );

 // Echo out the string of terms from the title
 echo $the_keywords;


function update_focus_keywords() {
    $posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'post' //replace post with the name of your post type
    ));
    foreach($posts as $p){
        if(get_the_tags($p->ID)){
            foreach((get_the_tags($p->ID)) as $tag) {
                $keywords[] = strtolower($tag->name);
            }
        update_post_meta($p->ID,'rank_math_focus_keyword',implode(", ", array_unique($keywords)));
        }
    }
    
}
```